# Groupby customer's id and keep the dates which are not null in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that consists of the date of the first and the last payment of a customer. The dates are in a separate column so the  dataset is something like this:

| id | first_payment | last_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 23/10/2010 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 24/11/2010 |
| 223 | 11/01/2012 | 0 |
| 223 | 0 | 12/02/2012 |

How do I group by id in order to look like this?

| id | first_payment | last_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 23/10/2010 | 24/11/2010 |
| 223 | 11/01/2012 | 12/02/2012 |

I used `groupby.df['id'].sum()` but cannot join the dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? I believe it is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774495/apply-coalesce-after-grouping-on-two-columns-in-pandas

Comment: I think you can replace those 0s with `NaN`, do a `groupby` on `id` and then `first`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the `first_payment` is the only non-zero first_payment column and the `last payment` is only non-zerovalue in the last_payment column, since you were trying to aggregate using the `sum()` method,  if that is true then you can do this:

```
df.replace('0',np.NaN)   # Replace zero by Null values
df.replace(0,np.NaN)     # If zeros are numerical
df_new = df.groupby('id').agg({'first_payment': 'first', 
                               'last_payment': 'last'})
```